# How do I delete tags in Feedly?

Tags: feedly

Is there a way to delete user created tags in Feedly?

Or any hack that I can use to delete tags, eg. using feedly API?

Answer (score 2):

Feedly changed this sometime before Aug 6, 2018. Now, you have to click the tag name in the left navigation bar, then click the three horizontal dots in the right pane where all of the tag options are, then select "Delete" from the context menu.

[image: Screenshot of the section where the configuration options are]

Wonky screenshot, but you can see the three dots over there on the right...

Answer (score 1):

This feature was implemented on 3/6/2014. [[source](https://feedly.uservoice.com/forums/192636-suggestions/suggestions/3830419-add-opportunity-to-delete-tags)]

Simply click the tag in the left menu, then click the *Delete* button near the name of the tag.

You'll be warned that the tag will be permanently removed from all included articles (even if the tag is empty). Confirm the deletion and it will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the tag in the left navigation bar, click on the delete button next to the tag name at the top of the page and confirm the delete.

http://blog.feedly.com/2014/03/03/fix-it-march-1-delete-tags/

Hope that helps.